# ListField(DictField()) with mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

How is it possible to ListField(DictField()) with mongoengine and access it, because the below code does not work?

```
from mongoengine import *

class Test():
    g = ListField(DictField(Mapping.build(
    test1=StringField(required=True),
    test2=StringField(required=True)
)))
```

Comment: The correct answer would be to use an embedded document instead of a DictField.

Answer (score 5):

I recognize that this post is very old, but for anyone finding this thread starting on using mongoengine. To improve on Niranj's answer, there now exists an `EmbeddedDocumentListField` and you need to inherit from `EmbeddedDocument` or `Document` in those classes.

```
class classEmbed(EmbeddedDocument):
    t = StringField()
    p = StringField()

class Test(Document):
    g = EmbeddedDocumentListField(classEmbed)
```

The documentation is [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:mhu0m-quQokJ:docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) under Fields

Answer (score 4):

Try using this format,

```
class classEmbed:
     t = StringField()
     p = StringField()

class Test:
     g = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(classEmbed))
```